# Friendly_id not working, redirects to Category with wrong index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, friendly-id

I've followed Ryan Bates' screencast in order to get friendly_id set up (up until the def should_generate_new_friendly_id? part) for my Category model. One of the Categories is books, but for some reason /categories/books redirects to a blank page, and the log shows that the server is trying to fetch a category with id=0 (which is wrong.) So here's what I've done:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
end
```

My migration:

```
class AddSlugToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :slug, :string
    add_index :categories, :slug
  end 
end
```

And last but not least, in rails console:

```
Category.find_each(&:save)
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Edit:

```
Started GET "/categories/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-02 13:03:29 -0500
  Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"books"}
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
  Item Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."category_id" = 0
Rendered categories/_items.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered categories/show.html.erb within layouts/application (20.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 139ms (Views: 69.1ms | ActiveRecord: 6.6ms)
```

Comment: @KyleMacey Not sure what you mean. I haven't added anything related to friendly_id in my routes.rb if that's what you mean.

Comment: Well even before that. Are you doing any special routing related to your categories? Also, can you post your controller?

Comment: @KyleMacey Nope, no special routing. Also, the controller is just scaffold generated, nothing added from friendly_id so I don't know why that would change anything.

Comment: do your slugs match your names? ie, did the save loop work the way it should?

Comment: @KyleMacey Yes, they are the same

Comment: @varatis - in your console, are you able to successfully return the correct record with Category.find('books'), if so, the problem could be friendly_id ... I noticed that the use: :history portion was broken in the 4.0 release. Try referencing the gem from the git repo and see if that helps.

Comment: @MateniaRossides Yeah the normal find works. I tried referencing from the repo, but 4.0.0 is actually the most recent.

Comment: @varatis does the log show where it's redirecting to? It would be great to see everything in the log that comes up when you access categories/books + the categories_controller. Please shoot through a Gist / Pastie.

Comment: @MateniaRossides Just posted what my log redirects to. It seems to try to pull by "id => books" which is wrong, but that just seems to indicate that friendly_id isn't doing its job

Comment: @varatis ..  Thanks for updating the post ... can you confirm that you are using 
`@category = Category.find(params[:id])`
and something along the lines of @items = @category.items  also I don't see your model having the has_many :items above (maybe you've stripped it down for the question?) .. I can gist what it should look like if you wish ...

Comment: @MateniaRossides Wow, I feel silly... I didn't have Category.find(params[:id]) in my controller. That was causing all the problems. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be more than just friendly_id ...  (see comments on original question)

It seems as though the category#show action is missing:

```
Category.find(params[:id])
```